# Can a variable function arguments list be passed by reference?

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

We can create functions with variable number of arguments using the `...` notation in stdarg library. Is it also possible to pass these arguments by reference? E.g. perhaps to return a variable number of output values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really (except with [template varargs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template)), for variadic functions in the sense of `<stdarg.h>`. You cannot call

```
void foo(int, ...);
```

as

```
int x = 0, y = 1;
foo(2,x,y);
```

and expect the `x` and `y`  to be passed by reference. However, you can pass their address:

```
foo(2, &x, &y);
```

And you probably could play variadic template tricks or preprocessor macros tricks to transform `FOO(x,y)` into `foo(2,&x,&y)`

Comment: Come to think of it, should have figured the trick on my own! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can't with `stdarg.h`, but if you use c++ features you could.

I'd recommend looking into the implementation of [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) as an example of how the standard library does this.

Comment: But this is a template vararg. OP asks about `<stdarg.h>`

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the reference to stdarg.h. I would doubt that there is any mechanism within that header to do this, seeing as how that header is a c header (which doesn't know that references exist).